# AngularJS $resource and .query()

Tags: django, angularjs

I have a simple app using AngularJS and Django.

```
app.factory('Settings', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/settings', null)
}]) //Here I get [{'foo': 'bar'}]

$scope.settings_raw = Settings.query()
```

I need to get only {'foo': 'bar'}.
I tried something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('settings_raw', function(){
    $scope.settings = $scope.settings_raw[0]
    console.log($scope.settings)
})
```

But I get undefined. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Settings.get(). It should do the trick.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource: { 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };